# Is there a function that convert a vector of [ 1 0 1 0 ] to [ 1 0 0 0 ]?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to keep the first '1' that appears in any every row.

example : i have a matrix ( an array of vectors ):

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

i want to make it like this:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

without for loops.
this was just an example, i need something that works on these kind of matrices.

thank you.

Comment: Your "Another explanation" would be a much better primary explanation for clarity on what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it can be done with whole matrix operations:

```
result = (np.cumsum(n,axis=1)*n==1).astype(int)
```

np.cumsum turns `[0,0,1,0,0,1]` into `[0,0,1,1,1,2]`.  Multiplication by `n` will keep zeroes where they were and will only produce 1*1=1 for the first 1 on the row.  So `[0,0,1,0,0,2] == 1` produces `[False,False,True,False,False,False]` which converts to `int` as `[0,0,1,0,0,0]`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simplest to use for loops as I haven't been able to find an elegant solution. However, this should work:

```
a = np.array([[1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0 ,0],
[1 ,0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
[0,0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,1, 0, 0 ,0 ,0]])

b = np.copy(a)
b[np.arange(len(a.shape[0])),np.argmax(a,axis=1)] = 0
a = a-b
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your vector is named `vec` and you want to change the number in position `x, y` to `z`. You could use this:

```
vec[y][x] = z
```

For this vector it would be:

```
vec[4][5] = 0
vec[5][5] = 0
```

Hope this works.

Comment: The answer you gave me is specific, i need something that works for any matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function, and use apply_along_axis to apply it. Technically it's not a for-loop, though it does have to apply to each row individually. That may or may not meet your requirements.

```
n=np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

def make_zero(x):
    x[x.argmax()+1:]=0
    return x

np.apply_along_axis(make_zero, 1,n)

array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```